# Create debian package from executable jar source without using any tools and scripts

Tags: java, ubuntu, debian, executable-jar

I have created a package based on http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html sample. In this sample, sources are c++ files. I want to create my new package from executable jar files source.
I found maven, ANT and dhBuild tools but I don't want to use this tools. So I need a way to create my package with command line. please give me some hints or samples to know most about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The goal is to create a package that simply puts a shell script where I want it.

1. Create a directory to build your packages in. Some use "deb" and others use "packages". Others create a directory structure for making multiple packages under "deb" (or whatever).

`mkdir deb`

2. Create the directory structure in deb that represents where you want the script to be placed1

mkdir -p ./deb/usr/local/bin

3.Copy the script into your new directory

```
cp /path/to/my/script/myscript.sh ./deb/usr/local/bin/
```

4.Make a subdirectory called "DEBIAN", this will host the package control file.

```
mkdir -p ./deb/DEBIAN
Create a control file.
touch ./deb/DEBIAN/control
```

5.Open the control file and enter the text below.

```
Package: myPackagename (no spaces or underscores allowed) 
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Maintainer: Maintainer Name <user@mail.com> 
Architecture: all 
Version: 1.0       
Depends: package1, package2, .........
Description: short description here 
 long description here (don't remove space at the beginning of 
 line(replace this with an empty line)
```

Change ownership:

```
sudo chown -R root:root ./deb
```

6.Create the debian package.

```
dpkg -b ./deb /my/output/destination/packagename.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

i fail to understand how "not using debhelper" and "creating a package from the cmdline" are contradictory.

however, since you explicitely asked about creating packages "without using any tools and scripts", here you go:

- dissect an existing package

  - a `.deb` file is really just a renamed **ar**chive, so you can do

    `$ ar xf /path/to/package.deb`
- study the contents of the package

      `$ ls
      debian-binary control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz`

  the `debian-binary` file contains the format-version of the package (usually `2.0`)

  the `data.tar.gz` file contains the actual data files.

  the `control.tar.gz` contains control information about the package, including it's name (and description), it's dependencies; but also pre-installation and post-installation scripts and the like.
- once you've learned the inner workings of a `.deb`-file, you can create one by inversing the above process:

  - tar your data into a `data.tar.gz`
  - create the control information for your `deb` and tar it into a `control.tar.gz`
  - create a `debian-binary` file containing the binary-version your are using:

      `$ echo "2.0" > debian-binary`
  - create a `deb` out of these files by running:

      `$ ar q /tmp/mypackage.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz`

however, you should do the above *only* if you really know what you are doing.
creating packages is not a trivial task.
that's why people have created a number of tools to help with the repetitive tasks.

use them!

Comment: The tar concept is not about jar file.

Comment: the `deb` concept is about `tar` (and `ar`). whether the archives (and tar-files) that form the `deb` contain `jar`, `zip`, binary magic or otherwise is unrelated to your question.